# DVI-VGA issue wih new nvidia drivers after electiricity down

Tags: drivers, nvidia-graphics-card, vga, dvi

i am using an old laptop (clevo with nvidia go 7950 GTX), Acer monitor(DVI), windows7(32-bit)

I was using forceware 2xx drivers before electiricty gone, after electiricty came monitor was not working. Then i realised nvidia control panel see the monitor connection as VGA but it is connected with DVI. So i tried newer forcewares or formatting OS but nothing worked. But i installed forceware 179 which is latest offical beta driver for go7950GTX, after old forceware monitor works fine with DVI connection(but as i told before i was using forceware 2xx until the electrcity problem and it was working perfect).

So what could cause this kind of problem? I want to use newer forceware for performance improvement(i use laptopvideo2go site to get latest forceware, they use inf files to pass compability issue, and it was working with 2xx driver series) ... i tried 3xx driver series too also not solve the problem. Also tried win7 x86 & x64 OS's and also not solved the problem.

edit-->> i bought new DVI cable .. and still not working... so i think laptop's interface has the problem :S and nothing to fix it :(

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have hardware issues.  Have you tried using a different monitor or using that monitor with a different computer?

Comment: well i was going to try this with other laptops but other laptops do not have DVI... by the way this monitor works with newer drivers but if only VGA cable withDVI converter :S (not directly with DVI cable) ... right now i installed old driver(179.48) and i can use this monitor with DVI cable ..... i will try new DVI cable when i get one ...and if i find a lapto pwith DVI output i will try that also :)